# Magento2 How to show sku in order summary?

Tags: magento2, checkout, order-summary

**I want to display sku in order summmary after product name.**

I've created pluging which will called `afterGetConfig` to modified **totalsData** you can see below code for it.

```
class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {
        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];

        for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){
        $items[$i]['sku'] = "dgd";

        }


        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then in `detail.html` i've added

```
<div class="details-sku">
                <span class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'Sku' --><!-- /ko --></span>
                <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.sku"></span>
            </div>
```

But i can't see sku value there. i can only see lable. see below screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: have you seen in console, window.checkoutconfig.totalsData ? This contain value of all item

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya No i've not check in console. but i've print it in pluging and i can see value there. I dont know where can i see in console. i can see lots of ajax response there.

Comment: can I get sku without creating a plugin?

Comment: @Joey Thanks I want additional attribute as well. this was just an example. appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Kul glad to be a help

Comment: I believe this is a much cleaner approach:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/234762/32198

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Override one template (simplification of Joey's answer). Bind directly to window object.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData object.

> app/design/frontend/MyCustomTheme/default/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/item/details.html

```
<!-- ko foreach: window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData -->
    <!-- ko if: item_id == $parents[1].item_id -->
        <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'SKU:'"></span>
        <!-- ko text: sku --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

"===" cant be used in `item_id == $parents[1].item_id` so we use "=="

Comment: Just to add to this,  in my case `item_id` is a string while `$parents[1].item_id` is a integer so `===` will not work. Used `==` and this method works great. Thanks

Comment: appreciated!! worked well for me

Answer (score 12):

In magento 2, you can display `sku` without creating any plugins, I'm just posting this answer to help out someone if needed..

Override

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html`
file or find that relevant file inside your theme. You should have `Magento_Checkout` inside your theme folder.

Add

`<strong class="product-item-sku" data-bind="text: getSku($parent.item_id)"></strong>`,

wherever you want.

Then override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/sum‌​mary/item/details.js`

file or find that relevant file inside your theme. You should have `Magento_Checkout` inside your theme folder. Then add `getSku` function to it.

your `details.js` file should looks like this with added `getSku` function,

```
/*** Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.*//*jshint browser:true
 jquery:true*//*global alert*/

define(['uiComponent'], function(Component) {
    "use strict";
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details'
        },
        getValue:

            function(quoteItem) {
                return quoteItem.name;
            },
        getSku: function(itemId) {
            var itemsData = window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData;
            var prodSku = null;
            itemsData.forEach(function(item) {
                if (item.item_id == itemId) {
                    prodSku = item.sku;
                }
            });
            if (prodSku != null) {
                return 'SKU: ' + prodSku;
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks Milan Pattani for his huge help

Comment: It's worked for me at Magento 2.3.1 as I was not getting custom field data at the payment review page.

Comment: Edit answer because while we copy the file path got this type vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/su‌​mmary/item/details.h‌​tml

Answer (score 2):

Facing this issue myself and not finding a clean answer I figured I would post how I approached this problem. The issue I see with the accepted answer is that it reloads the entire product resource just to get the sku.

So to prevent this performance overhead from happening (and what I think is a "cleaner" approach to solving this issue):

Create a preference in your modules etc/di.xml for \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\Item

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\Item"
            type="Your\Module\ClassOverrides\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\Item"/>
</config>
```

in this class create a set and get method for sku

```
<?php
namespace Your\Module\ClassOverrides\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals;

class Item extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals\Item
{
    public function getSku()
    {
        return $this->_get('sku');
    }

    public function setSku($sku)
    {
        return $this->setData('sku', $sku);

    }
}
```

and presto: the sku is now added to the item collection returned from getItems() and accessible via knockout.js in templates such as Magento_Checkout/template/summary/item/details.html via:

```
<div>
    Sku:
    <span data-bind="text: $parent.sku"></span>
</div>
```

Normally i try to avoid class overrides due to upgradability but this really isn't changing the core methods just adding a setter and getter for sku to the class. Im assuming this will work with any other product attribute as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've found solution. below is working code.

```
class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {
        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];

        for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){
        $items[$i]['sku'] = "dgd";

        }

        $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Hope this help other people.

Comment: Can you please help me with creating plugin? I need to add a custom product attribute to order summary below product name.

Answer (score 0):

try `$result['totalsData']['items'][$i]['sku']="dgd";` instead of `$items[$i]['sku'] = "dgd";`

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks. But i found problem was different. `$items = $result['totalsData']['items'];

        for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){
        $items[$i]['sku'] = "dgd";

        }                                  $result['totalsData']['items'] =   $items;
`